# compile error on g++ and not VisualStudio

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

I tried to replicate a minimalist example of my problem, with the following code :

http://codepad.org/HjhNSk2S

It does compile perfectly with Visual Studio 2008, just displays some warnings on codepad (about the order of initialization), but fails with g++ on cygwin, giving the following errors, and I just have no clue why :

```
Interpolator2.cpp:39: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
Interpolator2.cpp: In constructor ‘Interpolator<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>::Interpolator(const std::vector<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>, std::allocator<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE> > >&, const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, const std::vector<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>, std::allocator<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE> > >&)’:
Interpolator2.cpp:45: error: ‘_wB’ was not declared in this scope
Interpolator2.cpp:46: error: ‘_sqrDist’ was not declared in this scope
Interpolator2.cpp:47: error: ‘_kernel’ was not declared in this scope
Interpolator2.cpp:48: error: ‘_interpolateBins’ was not declared in this scope
Interpolator2.cpp:49: error: ‘_kNNDist’ was not declared in this scope
Interpolator2.cpp:50: error: ‘_NLevels’ was not declared in this scope
Interpolator2.cpp: At global scope:
Interpolator2.cpp:131: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
Interpolator2.cpp: In constructor ‘InterpModeData<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>::InterpModeData(int, double, const std::vector<std::vector<TsFlow, std::allocator<TsFlow> >, std::allocator<std::vector<TsFlow, std::allocator<TsFlow> > > >&, Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE> (*)(const Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>&, const Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>&, double), std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >&, double (*)(const Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>&, const Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>&, double), const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, const std::vector<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>, std::allocator<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE> > >&, const std::vector<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>, std::allocator<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE> > >&)’:
Interpolator2.cpp:135: error: ‘_sumWA’ was not declared in this scope
Interpolator2.cpp:135: error: ‘_sumWB’ was not declared in this scope
Interpolator2.cpp:135: error: ‘_samples’ was not declared in this scope
Interpolator2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Interpolator2.cpp:206: error: no matching function for call to ‘Interpolator<2, double>::Interpolator(std::vector<Vector<2, double>, std::allocator<Vector<2, double> > >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, std::vector<Vector<2, double>, std::allocator<Vector<2, double> > >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, <unresolved overloaded function type>, <unresolved overloaded function type>, int, int)’
Interpolator2.cpp:43: note: candidates are: Interpolator<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>::Interpolator(const std::vector<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>, std::allocator<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE> > >&, const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, const std::vector<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>, std::allocator<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE> > >&) [with int DIM = 2, SAMPLESTYPE = double]
Interpolator2.cpp:36: note:                 Interpolator<2, double>::Interpolator(const Interpolator<2, double>&)
Interpolator2.cpp: In member function ‘void Interpolator<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>::interpolate(double, const std::vector<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>, std::allocator<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE> > >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&) [with int DIM = 2, SAMPLESTYPE = double]’:
Interpolator2.cpp:212:   instantiated from here
Interpolator2.cpp:58: error: no matching function for call to ‘InterpModeData<2, double>::InterpModeData(unsigned int&, double&, std::vector<std::vector<TsFlow, std::allocator<TsFlow> >, std::allocator<std::vector<TsFlow, std::allocator<TsFlow> > > >&, Vector<2, double> (*&)(const Vector<2, double>&, const Vector<2, double>&, double), std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >&, double (*&)(const Vector<2, double>&, const Vector<2, double>&, double), std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, std::vector<Vector<2, double>, std::allocator<Vector<2, double> > >&, std::vector<Vector<2, double>, std::allocator<Vector<2, double> > >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, const std::vector<Vector<2, double>, std::allocator<Vector<2, double> > >&)’
Interpolator2.cpp:133: note: candidates are: InterpModeData<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>::InterpModeData(int, double, const std::vector<std::vector<TsFlow, std::allocator<TsFlow> >, std::allocator<std::vector<TsFlow, std::allocator<TsFlow> > > >&, Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE> (*)(const Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>&, const Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>&, double), std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >&, double (*)(const Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>&, const Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>&, double), const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, const std::vector<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>, std::allocator<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE> > >&, const std::vector<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE>, std::allocator<Vector<DIM, SAMPLESTYPE> > >&) [with int DIM = 2, SAMPLESTYPE = double]
Interpolator2.cpp:127: note:                 InterpModeData<2, double>::InterpModeData(const InterpModeData<2, double>&)
```

Any idea ? 
Thanks!!

Comment: If you have a constructor function with that many arguments, you should consider refactoring.  Also, use `typedef`s!  Your code would be much easier to read.

Comment: Please post a minimal code example which illustrates the problem in your actual question rather than linking to another site.

Comment: The error is on line 39 of a 215-line file... that's not a minimalist example :-)  Try cutting out a lot of the code after that line, and check you still get the same error message.

Comment: these 200 lines were extracted from a 1000+ lines file to illustrate the problem... I'll try removing more

Comment: (P.S. to be clear, the error that matters is always the first one.  The rest are probably happening because the compiler is confused by the first error.  So get a minimal example for the "expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant" error)

Comment: It compiles successfully with warnings on ideone [http://ideone.com/r5JaP](http://ideone.com/r5JaP)

Comment: Paul R : the main constructor has 9 arguments which define the problem I am solving. The other constructors just allow to pass datastructures to threads. Anyway, this is a research code that I'd like to make public : I'll leave anyone who is interested refactor it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is illegal to use identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, e.g. `_B` on line 39.

The compiler has probably `#define`d that to be an integral constant, which would explain your error. Try changing it to a valid identifier.

Comment: Great, thank you very much ! I didn't know that, and now it compiles fine :)

Comment: @WhitAngl: It's also illegal to use a double underscore anywhere in an identifier. You didn't do that here, but it's good to know :-)

Comment: @Peter: Additionally it is also illegal to name an identifier starting with a single underscore and a lower case letter if the identifier is used in the global namespace. This completes the three restrictions :)